# Problem with push

Tags: solidity, addresses, arrays

This is my code. When i push address into participants the length is zero. Why?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0
contract Registration {
    address public owner;
    uint threshold = 2;
    address [] participants;
    // The addres is used to map on the balances that we have
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    uint conceptPrice;
    enum Stage{Initial, Registered, Modifiable, Done}
    Stage public stage = stage = Stage.Initial;
    function concept(uint _conceptPrice) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        stage = Stage.Registered;
    }
    function saveContra() public constant returns (uint numParticipants){
        if (stage != Stage.Registered) return;
        participants.push(msg.sender);
        if (participants.length > threshold) {
            mineConcept();
        }
        //It is 0
        numParticipants = participants.length;
    }
    function mineConcept(){
        balances[owner] += 100;
        for (uint i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
            balances[participants[i]] += 1;
        }
        stage = Stage.Modifiable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your contract, but the reason why you are getting a return of 0 is NOT because it is returning `numParticipants`, but because your code is exiting at:

```
if (stage != Stage.Registered) return;
```

Likely, you have not called `function concept()`, which means stage was never set to `Stage.Registered`. Then that `if` statement fails, and returns nothing, which in Solidity uint is 0.

To fix some of the problems going on in your contract:

- You should not mark the `saveContra()` function as constant since it modifies the state of participants.
- You should probably change `function concept()` to `contructor()` so that it is run when your contract deploys, automatically setting the `owner` and the `stage`
- You should have your contract ["fail early, and fail loud"](https://oncodingstyle.blogspot.com/2008/10/fail-early-fail-loudly.html) when there are conditions not met. So rather than `if (stage != Stage.Registered) return;`, you should write `require(stage == Stage.Registered)`. Now when this condition is not satisfied, your contract will `revert`, something that would have helped you debug this issue to begin with.

These are just a few suggestions to get started, but not a comprehensive list of other issues in your contract.